# Why is [Math Processing Error] all over the place today?

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm seeing [Math Processing Error] all over this site today. Is there a bug or is this problem unique to me? How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Shift-Refresh?

Comment: I'm also seeing this everywhere on the site with Chrome, but it seems to work with Firefox

Comment: I was just googling the same thing. I have the same problem with Chromium 16, in linux.

Comment: @J.M. Shift-Refresh worked. Could you fill in some details? What is Shift-Refresh and why was I having the problem? Thanks.

Comment: It means crap got in your browser cache. Shift+Refresh forces your browser to pull JS and other stuff anew instead of getting them from the cache.

Comment: Is there a version of Shift-Refresh for iPhone?

Comment: @Asaf: yes, you hold the home and lock buttons for 7-10 seconds :)

Comment: It also happened to me in Chrome (not Firefox) and Shift+F5 (which is apparently Fn+F5 on my HP laptop) works. I have no idea what the issue was.

Comment: Would one of you (maybe @JM) make an answer?

Comment: I'm wondering if chrome has resently implemented a security feature that timesout your javascript if running on the localhost...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Per popular demand:

One of the first things you should do when MathJax is crapping out on you is to try a hard refresh, which is executed by holding your <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and then clicking the Refresh/Reload/whatever button in your favorite browser. Browsers usually cache stuff like images and JS bits to ease the task of loading a page. Since this cache is sometimes prone to getting crap on it one would sometimes want to do a hard refresh so that the browser is forced to pull stuff from the servers instead of from its cache.

The more drastic method is to do an actual cache clear (see your browser's help file for details) and restart. If all else fails, consider dropping a line here on meta, or for really severe problems, the MathJax team.

Comment: This doesn't solve it for me. I see the formula for a second but then the error jumps and the formula disappears.